# Actions on Google's Smart home SYNC works, but showing an error message

Tags: actions-on-google

I am developing the new smart home app in Actions on Google.

In Google Home APP -> home control -> add devices, I can find my smart home app.
After passing through the OAuth 2 authorization process, it sends action.devices.SYNC to my web service and showing linking to your account on the screen.

Then my web service responds with the device list. Here is the response sent back:

```
{"requestId":"16673404925179824463","payload":{"devices":[{"id":"DEVICE_ID","type":"action.devices.types.OUTLET","traits":["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],"name":{"defaultNames":["Chris Switch"],"name":"Chris Switch","nicknames":["Chris Switch"]},"willReportState":false,"deviceInfo":{"manufacturer":"AIONE Lifestyle Studio Inc.,","model":"SPM185","hwVersion":"1.0","swVersion":"8.0"}}]}}
```

But then an error message appear in the bottom of the Google Home APP saying "couldn't update the setting, please check your connection".
Then I returned to the device list and found the device is already added to Google Home. Afterwards, I can control it through voice commands.

So the whole process is working but I just wonder why the error message would appear?

Comment: The issue disappeared just now... I relink my account and no error message showed. My web service is not modified. Should I keep this question here for reference or just delete it?